# 1.000.000 writes/second with Firebase (with transaction)

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

With Firebase can you think of a database to have a global counter with the possibility of having 1.000.000 writes per second (with transaction) ?

**With Cloud Firestore** and [Distributed counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) I can have (at most) :

- ( 1 write/second * 100) == **100 write per second**.

( 100 : [Limit maximum depth of subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas))

**With Real time Database** and 1000 database :

- ( 1000 writes/second * 1000) == **1.000.000 write per second**.

But scale up to 1000 databases can be quite long.
Are there any other solutions?

Thanks you.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. What is this for?

Comment: Assuming you have an app with 100 milion of downloads, having 1 milion simultaneous writes is not that strange

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or are you asking about a [a specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If it's about a coding issue can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of that issue? It's a bit vague as to what the question is asking - also it's unclear what is considered a 'write' (as in how much data a 'write' is) and in what use case this would come up.

Comment: It is a theoretical question, but I am thinking of a project where it might be necessary to have many transactions on the same variable very simultaneously ( a transaction simply writes text, not images ), ideas? Thank you.